Convert current Ubuntu installation to VirtualBox or Live USB
Currently I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 and facing many problems so, after 4 years, I decided that it's time to do a fresh install on my machine. But I have so many settings, apps, files, vpns and other (it's my work machine) so it's really hard and frustrating to think what I have to remember and backup before I do the format.
It would be ideal if I could create an image of the entire system (it has 240 GB) that I can run on my other laptop (either as Live USB, although I don't have USB bigger than 64 GB, or through Virtual Box) so that I recreate the same experience when you're changing to another laptop.
That way I can just format the current one without the fear of losing anything and then slowly restore one by one piece as I notice that something is missing. And after a few months, when everything settles down, I can just delete the image. And yes, I know that I can just backup all the files, but I would also like to be able to access the apps because of settings, accounts etc.
I've already looked through many other posts with same question but was unable to find anything that might help me. Either the tools are discontinued, or don't work with systems > 8 GB or they work only with Debian. Is there any tool in 2024 that can help me?

Install the new version on the same machine and use the option to install beside. You then have both and you can run either one as you wish.

I would like to do a full wipe of the disc + I cannot run both at the same time so it has to be on another laptop.
